# Question about iterated covariant derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry

In another post of mine, "Writing inner product of Hessians as a sum of inner product" it was clarified a dout about a misunderstanding of notation since $\nabla_i\nabla_jf\neq\nabla_i(\nabla_jf)$, but now I'm reading the paper "Minimal immersions of 2-manifolds into spheres" of Michael Kozlowski and Udo Simon and in equation (2.1a) the authors wrote

\begin{equation}
\langle x_{ijkl},x^{jl}g^{ik}\rangle  =  \langle\nabla_l(x_{ijk}),x^{jl}g^{ik}\rangle
\end{equation}

Why is this true?

Comment: In general it is not correct. Is $x$ the immersion?

Comment: Does that just mean $(\nabla _l x)_{ijk}$?

Comment: John, $\tilde x:M\to S^{n}$ is a isometric minimal immersion into $S^n$, $j:S^n\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is the canonical embedding and $x:=j\circ \tilde x$ is the position vector of the isometric immersion into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Is the equality true because $\nabla$ means the Euclidean derivative?

Comment: In the paper, it means $(\nabla_l x)_{ijk}$. $x$ is considered an  $(n+1)$ collection of functions on $M$, and $\nabla$ is the connection on $M$.

Comment: Sorry but, why does this solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

With $\nabla_l (x_{ijk})$ the author means $\nabla_l x_{ijk}$ or, arguably more clearly, $(\nabla_\cdot x_{\cdot\cdot\cdot})_{likj}$. The brackets are there only because he's going to expand the inner term. This convention is retained in the following lines.

I don't think anyone would ever write $\nabla_l (x_{ijk})$ to mean "the $l$-derivative of the function obtained by deriving $x$ with respect to $i$, $j$ and $k$". It would be very confusing and non-standard.

Comment: My question was motivated exactly by the second part of your answer: If $\nabla_lx_{ijk}$ does not mean "the $l-$derivative of the function obtained..." then, why can the authors write $\nabla_lx_{ijk}=\nabla_l(x_{ikj}+...)$ like if we had iterated derivatives? (Remark: I know that $x_{ijk}=x_{ikj}+....$ is the Ricci identy.)

Comment: What they mean is that, by definition, $\nabla_l x_{ijk} = (\nabla x)_{lijk}$: all the indices are to be evaluated _after_ all covariant derivatives (and everything else). It is just a writing shortcut. In particular: $\nabla_l x_{ijk} = (\nabla x)_{lijk} = (\nabla (x + \dots))_{likj} = \nabla_l (x_{ikj} + \dots)$. Does this help?

Comment: In other words, if $x$ is (like in your case) a $3$-covariant tensor, then by definition $\nabla x$ is a $4$-covariant tensor (defined as $(\nabla x)_{lijk} = \partial_l x_{ijk} + \text{part with Christoffel symbols}$). So what you mean is $(\nabla x)_{lijk}$, but you write it down $\nabla_l x_{ijk}$ to save on key strokes.